# Algebra Precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $a> 0 < b$  For all the integer value of $a$ and $b$
>
> $X= (a^2 + ab)-(ab^2-b)/(2a^2+b^2 -ab)$
>
> Quantity I: $x $
>   Quantity II: $1.5$

(a) Quantity I $\lt$ Quantity II
(b) Quantity I $\gt$ Quantity II
(c) Quantity I $\ge$ Quantity II
(d) Quantity I $=$ Quantity II
(e) No relation

> $(x^a)^c = x^c$
>
> $x^{2b}/x^a = (x^{5a}) * (x^d)*(x^b)$
>
> Quantity I = $b$
>
> Quantity II = $d$

(a) Quantity I $\gt$ Quantity II
(b) Quantity I $\lt$ Quantity II
(c) Quantity I $\ge$ Quantity II
(d) Quantity I $=$ Quantity II
(e) No relation

**Generally How to solve this sum and how to approach this Question,please guide me the steps with the answer**

Comment: $(x^a)^c = x^c$ ?? you mean $x^{ac}$ ?

Comment: No x^c only and then x^5a, a should come in power ,x2b b also should come in power@A---B guide me the answer with steps please

Comment: Ok is it $x^{5a}$ or $x^5 *a$ same for $x^{2b}$ ?

Comment: Still $x^{ac} \ne x^c$ unless $a = 1$.

Comment: Because you are not clarifying the question.

Comment: @A---B what you  are expecting

Comment: See until you tell which of $a = 1$ and $(x^a)^c = x^{ac}$ is true, I can't answer.

Comment: Both can't be true.

Comment: I assume $a = 1$. then $$x^{2b}/x^a = (x^{5a}) * (x^d)*(x^b) \implies x^{2b}/x = (x^{5}) * (x^d)*(x^b) \implies x^{2b} = (x^{6}) * (x^{d+1})*(x^{b+1})  \implies x^{2b - b - 1} = (x^{6}) * (x^{d+1})\implies x^{b - 1} =  (x^{d+7}) \implies x^{b - 1 - d - 7} =  1  \implies x^{b- d - 8} =  1 \implies b = d+8$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $a = 1$
Then,
$$x^{2b}/x^a = (x^{5a}) * (x^d)*(x^b) \implies x^{2b}/x = (x^{5}) * (x^d)*(x^b) \implies x^{2b} = (x^{6}) * (x^{d+1})*(x^{b+1})  \implies x^{2b - b - 1} = (x^{6}) * (x^{d+1})\implies x^{b - 1} =  (x^{d+7}) \implies x^{b - 1 - d - 7} =  1  \implies x^{b- d - 8} =  1 \implies b = d+8$$

Therefore $b > d$ option a is correct.

---

$x= (a^2 + ab)-(ab^2-b)/(2a^2+b^2 -ab)$

Since $b <0$ let $-c = b, c \in \mathbb{R^+}$

$$x= (a^2 - ac)-{(ac^2+c)\over(2a^2+c^2 +ac)}$$

$$x= {(a^2 - ac)(2a^2+c^2 +ac)-(ac^2+c)\over(2a^2+c^2 +ac)} = {2a^4 - a^3c-c^3a-ac^2-c\over(2a^2+c^2 +ac)}$$

By AM-GM,

$$x\ge {2a^4 - 2a^2c^2-ac^2-c\over(2a^2+c^2 +ac)} \ge  {4a^4 - 4a^2c^2-2ac^2-2c\over(5a^2+3c^2)}$$

Let $c = 1$

Therefore,
$$x\ge  {4a^4 - 4a^2-2a-2\over(5a^2+3)}$$

Now let $a = 10$ , then $x \ge 78$

and as you said $x = 0$ for $a = 1, b= -1$.

Therefore option e is correct.

Comment: In 1 you could have directly plugged the values, but I just simplify so that I solve it.

Comment: ok Thankyou for your hardwork, if you like my question please upvote it@A---B,I have understood very clearly